# PyCharm launch command on SSH

Tags: c, bash, shell, ssh, pycharm

How can I create a configuration that connects to one of the PyCharm's SSH configuration and start a docker compose application (I just need to run `docker-compose up` so it is could be the equivalent of executing a shell command).

Thanks